# Alternatives for AlarmManager setRepeating in API 19 and above?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeat

My app requires very accurate timing of a repeating alarm. Since API 19 the AlarmManager setRepeating is now inexact to save battery ( Save the trees and all ).

Is there any workaround to get API 19's setExact method to work on a loop?

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Seems like they give a pretty straightforward explanation of how to do things?

Comment: I have a task running at an accurate time.

Alarmmanager setRepeating used to work fine for this Job. Now since API 19 and above it can run very late due to them grouping alarms together before running.

setExact would do the job but I need a repeating version of this. I have a service that runs a task every 5 minutes for example.

Answer (score 5):

If Google provides a `setExactRepeating()` method, it may solve your problem. (It's a joke)

For now, you have to reschedule the alarm by yourself.

1. use the `setExact()` method to schedule the alarm for the first time, for example:

   alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, pendingIntent);
2. reschedule the alarm in the `onReceiver()` of your BroadcastReceiver, the repeating time is a day(`AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY` in the following code):

   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

   ```
       Context danielContext = MonitorApp.getContext();
       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       Intent i = new Intent(context, ReceiverName.class);//put your own ReceiverName
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
       alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
   ```

   }

Of course, do something in the `onReceiver()` method to achieve your aim.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any workaround to get API 19's setExact method to work on a loop?

Sure. Have your `BroadcastReceiver`, or whatever is getting control from the alarm, call `setExact()` to schedule the next recurrence, in addition to doing its existing work.

Bear in mind, though, that [the changes to background processing in Android M](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/03/random-musing-m-developer-preview-ugly-part-one.html) may cause you difficulty.